# EF Creating business objects in Linq or in foreach

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am measuring differences in query execution and stumbled upon a case I have no explanation for. The query should retrieve 10000 customers with their main address (a customer can have many addresses). We used 2 different methods with Navigation Properties which differ greatly in execution time.

The first method retrieves the customers the way I usually write Linq queries: write the results directly to a business object and calling ToList(). This method takes 25 seconds to execute.

The second method retrieves the customers as a list of EF Entities first. The EF Entities are converted to business objects in a foreach loop. This method takes 2 seconds to execute.

Can someone explain the difference? And is it possible to modify the first method so the execution time is similar to the second?

```
private List<ICustomer> NavigationProperties_SO(int method)
{
   using (Entities context = new Entities())
   {
      context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

      context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
      context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

      List<ICustomer> customerList = new List<ICustomer>();
      if (method == 1)
      {
         // Execution time: 25 seconds
         customerList = (from c in context.cust
                                           .Include(o => o.AddressList)
                                           .Include(o => o.AddressList.Select(p => p.ADDR))
                             let mainAddress = c.AddressList.Where(o => o.Main_addr == "1").FirstOrDefault()
                             select new Customer
                             {
                                cust = c,
                                mainAddress = mainAddress,
                                addr = mainAddress == null ? null : mainAddress.ADDR
                             }).AsNoTracking().ToList<ICustomer>();
      }
      else if (method == 2)
      {
         // Execution time: 2 seconds
         var tempList = (from c in context.cust
                                           .Include(o => o.AddressList)
                                           .Include(o => o.AddressList.Select(p => p.ADDR))
                         select c).AsNoTracking().ToList();
         foreach (var c in tempList)
         {
            ICustomer customer = new Customer();
            var mainaddress = c.AddressList.Where(o => o.Main_addr == "1").FirstOrDefault();
            customer.cust = c;
            customer.mainAddress = mainaddress;
            customer.addr = mainaddress == null ? null : mainaddress.ADDR;
            customerList.Add(customer);
         }
      }
      return customerList;
   }
}
```

**Edit**

Here are the (simplified) queries generated by Entity Framework:

Method 1

```
SELECT 
*
FROM   [DBA].[CUST] AS [Extent1]
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP ( 1 ) 
    *
    FROM [DBA].[CUST_ADDR] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE (([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]) AND (N'1' = [Extent2].[Main_addr])
    ORDER BY 'a' ) AS [Limit1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [DBA].[ADDR] AS [Extent3] ON [Limit1].[Id] = [Extent3].[Id]
```

Method 2

```
SELECT 
*
FROM ( SELECT 
    *
    FROM  [DBA].[CUST] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT *
        FROM  [DBA].[CUST_ADDR] AS [Extent2]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [DBA].[ADDR] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent3].[Id] ) AS [Join1] ON ([Extent1].[Id] = [Join1].[Id])
)  AS [Project1]
```

The difference is that the first method does the filtering in the query (´let´) while the second method retrieves all records and filters in the loop.

Comment: Did you execute this multiple time, in different orders (method 2 first sometimes, method 1 first on other times) ? I would suspect the `FirstOrDefault` part to generate a "complicated" sql. Did you look at the sql generated by both query, and try to execute them in db to see the difference ?

Comment: I always executed the queries separately and restarted the application. I added the generated sql to my post. The first query filters on the database and executes in 25s on the db. The second query shows all addresses (and filters in code) and executes in 2s. I would like to be able to determine beforehand when to use which syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect

```
let mainAddress = c.AddressList.Where(o => o.Main_addr == "1").FirstOrDefault()
```

is the culprit. Certain queries forces EF to ask for all possible combinations to be returned. EF then spends a little time narrowing down the scope before it provides you with a reasonable result set. You can use SQL Server Profiler to look at the queries generated.

In any case, you can use LINQ, rather than a foreach, at the end of your second method (this won't help performance, but readability might improve):

```
return tempList.Select(c => new Customer{cust=c, mainAddress = c.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.Main_addr=="1"), ...);
```

Comment: I agree that the ´let´ syntax generates a more complex query because the filtering happens in the query itself and not in the code as in method 2. I've added the generated queries to my post. I find the first method more intuitive and would like a uniform way to write all queries if possible (and not create them through trial and error). Your suggestion for the second method has the disadvantage that the check for the main address must be repeated 3 times, while in the ´foreach´ it can be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer related to comments... (but two long for a comment)*

**For the "how to choose the best syntax" part**

I would say that it comes partially from "experience" (see, 9Rune5 and I suspected the same point, which was the problematic one before seeing the generated sql) : but experience, sometimes, may also leed to wrong conclusions ;)

So to be a little bit more pragmatic, I would suggest you to use tools/libs which will help you to look at the generated sql / time by query, or page...

ANTS Performance profiler, Miniprofiler, Sql Server profiler, etc, it may depend on your technologies / needs...

**By the way, if you want to keep a "linq" syntax, you could go for**

```
var tempList = context.cust
                      .Include(o => o.AddressList)
                      .Include(o => o.AddressList.Select(p => p.ADDR))
                      .AsNoTracking()
                      .ToList();

var result = (from c in tempList
             let mainAddress = c.AddressList.Where(o => o.Main_addr == "1").FirstOrDefault()
             select new Customer
                    {
                         cust = c,
                         mainAddress = mainAddress,
                         addr = mainAddress == null ? null : mainAddress.ADDR
                     }).ToList<ICustomer>();
```

But not really less verbose than the foreach syntax...

Comment: Thank you for your addition. I do have some experience in Entity Framework but what bothers me about it is that a query can be written in a number of ways and it's not clear which one is more performant until you try it. I have refactored queries with Navigation Properties to Joins (and the other way around) or doing separate queries and combining them in code to gain performance. There just doesn't seem to be a general rule of thumb as when to use which syntax. A best practices guide would be useful :).

Comment: @BrunoV sure ;) I wouldn't mean that you had no experience, by the way, I am still often suprised by performances (many queries involved by lazy loading more performant than one big query generated by eager loading, for example)... Sadly the try and error is sometimes the only way to go !